# Is it possible to reduce the size of a VM disk on Azure

Tags: azure

Is it possible to reduce the size of a VM disk?

I have a 500 GB disk with 20 GB of occupation.
I want to reduce the size to 100GB. The Azure Portal only allows you to increase. How can I reduce the size?

The VM has the UBUNTU operating system.

Comment: is it the OS disk or a second disk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can shrink you VM size

1. First, create a new Data disk from the Azure portal. Select ‘Create disk‘ and follow the wizard to create a managed disk.
2. Next, RDP to the VM in order to initialize the new disk. Go to Disk Management and assign a size and Drive letter for the new volume.
3. Once the new volume is initialized, move the files from the source disk to the new volume. This can be done using the robocopy.

If you are looking for other option you can refer below link as well
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-shrink-a-managed-disk/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's only possible to do this by reducing the size of a snapshot and then creating a new VM from that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/642191/need-to-reduce-data-disk-size-of-linux-vm-on-azure